# Remove an item from a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

why cant I select remove or delete? I want to remove a record from a list

```
IEnumerable<StockLocation_Table> AllCurrentStocklocations = db.StockLocation_Table.ToList();
List<StockLocation> StockLocations = ServerHelper.GetStockLocationsBatch(BatchUrl, i, batchSize);

foreach (StockLocation_Table _stock_table in AllCurrentStocklocations)
{
    foreach (StockLocation _stock in StockLocations)
    {
        if (_stock.ServerLocationId == _stock_table.ServerLocationId)
        {
            AllCurrentStocklocations.?? why cant i say remove._stock_table 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it is `IEnumerable<T>` and the `Remove` method is not defined in `IEnumerable<T>`.Since you are using `ToList` just use a `List<T>` as type:

```
List<StockLocation_Table> AllCurrentStocklocations = db.StockLocation_Table.ToList();
```

Edit: Also you can't modify the collection inside of *foreach* loop.You can use LINQ instead:

```
var AllCurrentStocklocations = db.StockLocation_Table
                    .Where(x => !StockLocations
                    .Any(s => s.ServerLocationId == x.ServerLocationId).ToList()
```

Comment: That would be removing an item from a collection being iterated.  It's also not really the appropriate solution to this problem.

Comment: @Servy you right I didn't notice that.now it should be okey

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do here is get all of the items from your DB table where the ID is not in this other list.  What you should do here is construct a query such that you get just those items without those IDs, rather than pulling down the entire DB table into a list, and then going through this other list *for each item*) to look for IDs so that you can remove the current item from this list.  In addition to being *super* inefficient, this would also mean removing the item from a collection being iterated, which would break the iterator.  Instead write something that can be translated into a DB query:

```
List<StockLocation> stockLocations = ServerHelper.GetStockLocationsBatch(
    BatchUrl, i, batchSize);
var locationIDs = stockLocations.Select(location => location.ServerLocationId);
db.StockLocation_Table.Where(item => 
    !locationIDs.Contains(item.ServerLocationId));
```

Comment: I agree with this answer.  It is always better to query the database for just the items you want.  With my database, it is on a server.  It takes a long time to download from the server, so getting less information makes the program run much faster.  Speed optimization is very important.